# Dictionary conversion to list in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of the example:
E = 527:{ ('GENERAL MOTORS CORP.', datetime.date(1, 1, 1), False, 'KENOSHA', 'WI')}

I need to take out the datetime.date(1,1,1) and turn this into a separate list outside of the tuple. I'm supposed to access the date for multiple keys and include them into a list. I'm very confused and looking to do this for a general for of any key. This is taken from a general data table where the key is index 1 and the values in the tuples are the next indexed values. 
Would [E[527][1] be correct?

Comment: I was provided a function to generate the dictionary from the data table. I have fieldict("TOP1000.txt") which assembles the values into the form shown above. How would I write it then to produce the list? Sorry I'm new to programming so I struggle with correct syntax rules – user1807854 46 secs ago edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
dates = [v[1] for k,v in E.iteritems()]
```

OR:

```
dates = [v[1] for v in E.itervalues()]
```

OR:

```
from operator import itemgetter

dates = map(itemgetter(1), E.itervalues())
```

As per you comment it can be something like:

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_dates(filename, A, B):
    with open(filename) as f:
        dates = [datetime.strptime(row.split()[2], format) for row in f.readlines()]
    dates = [dt for dt in dates if dt.year == A and dt.month == B]
    return [(dt, dates.count(dt)) for dt in set(dates)]
```

Comment: I was provided a function to generate the dictionary from the data table. I have fieldict("TOP1000.txt") which assembles the values into the form shown above. How would I write it then to produce the list? Sorry I'm new to programming so I struggle with correct syntax rules

Comment: Would I return fieldict("TOP1000.txt")?

Comment: update your question with the sample - it's not very clear what do you want. Just try to describe the default workaround you need by steps and give us sample

Comment: It's a smaller part of my assignment but I'll just post that so maybe it will help:  Read DOT1000.txt and return a list of (d,ct)
  pairs, where d is a date object of the form
     datetime.date(A,B,C)
  having A equal to the year argument and 
  B equal to the month argument to eventfreq(year,month).
  The ct part of each pair is the number of records 
  that had a date equal to datetime.date(A,B,C).
We are provided with a function to generate the dictionary in the for of d = "key" = {tuple}

Comment: The output looks like:  >>> evlist[14]
  (datetime.date(1995, 1, 15), 1)

Comment: check my answer it not precisly what you want - but it can give you an idea - it's still not clear for me what do you actually need. In any case it looks like another question so you have to create a new question with the details in it

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I agree the question is vague and me being new to programming makes it difficult to figure out how to articulate my problem correctly.

Comment: If my answer help you just accept it or upvote = otherwise not

Answer (score 0):

```
[ t[1] for _, t in E.iteritems() ]
```